# Why can't SO change the @ comment from @Username to @userid

Tags: discussion

Because changing the current @username from @userid (atleast internally) can reflect the changed username / handle easily.

Comment: Self answering works in a differnt way. In the question part you write your question and you add an answer below in the **Your Answer** section

Comment: I mean, at least in the background they can be based on `userid` so that they won't break when user changes his `username`

Comment: @TechExchange nothing breaks, the `@` cause single notification to be sent once the comment was submitted, that's it. It has no further purpose. If the name later changes you just see `@` followed by the old name but that does not break anything. What I mean is that it's *not* meant to act as "in reply to a certain comment".

Comment: Well, I love the fact [that username changes get archived that way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122937/what-is-the-purpose-of-leaving-this-2-answer-as-is#comment327263_122939).

Comment: If there is some communication like as @ xxx mentioned and @ xxx changed to @yyy , meaning is broken isn't it

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby indeed, I often use this to track down deleted accounts to find out who it was! :)

Answer (score 6):

It's not that they *can't*, more so that they *won't*, and here's two reasons why, I think:

- Comments are secondary citizens and often noise, in danger of deletion with no real posterity held,
- and, given the above, it makes the extra overhead of doing so overkill.

There are other reasons, but mainly, considering them all together, there's no added value.